# How could I show product name in the input box when selecting with keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

The previous member wrote an angular js for autocomplete search.

When I type some keywords it will return me the candidates.

However when I nav those candidates with arrow keys, it will appear the `product id` in the input box, I want to show the `product name`.

How could I do it with `angular js` ?

> item.label is product name, and item.value is product id

I'm not familiar with it, thanks so much

[image]

## js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search_bar").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
                 console.log(request['term']);
                 name = "name="+request['term'];
                 $.ajax({
                     url: "/v1/search/",
                     type: "GET",
                     data: name,
                     success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                         response($.map(data, function (el) {
                             return {
                                 label: el.name,
                                 value: el.id
                             };
                         }));
                     }
                 });
            },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $("#search_bar").val(ui.item.label);
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#search_bar").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#search_bar_id").val(ui.item.value);
            window.location.href = '/browse/'+ui.item.value;
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Here is [auto-complete for angular](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput) and [Demo](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos)

Comment: Your code is not AngularJs, but looks very much like jQuery. Also, the change you request is trivial, so are you sure you know what you are doing and could incorporate a correct answer into your code?

Answer (score 0):

angular-ui's typeahead works great! You can use this:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/typeahead